# Display 2 items in Flatlist in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

With the help of flat list, I'm able to render the items that scrolls horizontally, refer below image:

[image: Image ref:]

I would like to restrict only 2 images with paging enabled. I'm using below code to display:

View:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Topics</Text>
        <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={styles.bookslist}
            pagingEnabled
            horizontal
            data={BookManager.getBooks()}
            renderItem={renderCoverImage}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={
                () => <View style={{ width: 16, backgroundColor: 'clear' }} />
            }
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({ length: 50, offset: 50 * index + 30, index })}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        padding: 20,
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 22
    },
    bookslist: {
        backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 50
    }
});
```

I tried and noticed that "getItemLayout" is not working. Am I missing something?
How can I just render 2 items only visible at a time. If any more items are there, I want to go with paging option. How to set the style or getItemLayout to achieve?

Comment: What's on the `renderCoverImage` function?

Comment: on this function you could add a counter and `if counter >= 2 { return }` or something similar

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior, I mentioned that I want to show only 2 items at a time and if more than that, it will be handled via "pagingEnabled" option (ie after scroll)

Comment: oh.. ok.. sorry